# Edit prefix when generate new angular 4 web app

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to edit prefix at component, service when generate new angular4 web app.I used options "--jhi-prefix" in command

> jhipster --jhi-prefix my-prefix

but doesn't work.

In file app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule,
    Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
```

In file navbar.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'jhi-navbar',
templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
styleUrls: [
    'navbar.scss'
]
```

})

Please help me edit prefix 'jhi' to my custom prefix.

Comment: This was supposed to be fixed in their 4.6.0 release per this issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6003. Unfortunately, I've tried it and it still does not seem to work. Is there a functional reason for switching the prefix?